# Normal varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the book "Toric Varieties" by Cox, Little and Schenck, page 39 one can read that the affine surface $Y \subset \mathbb C^4$ parametrized by $(s^4,s^3t, st^3, t^4)$ is not normal.

I heard that normal means for a variety, being no singular in codimension 1. So I was waiting to find a curve $C \subset Sing(Y)$ but I couldn't, and found that the singular locus of $Y$ is only the origin : the singular points of $Y$ are the $(s,t)$ such that $rank \pmatrix{ 4s^3 & 3s^2t & t^3 & 0 \\ 0 & s^3 & 3t^2s & 4t^3  } \leq 1$
.

Where am I mistaken ?

Comment: You are not mistaken about the singular locus in your case is not of codimension one, but two. You are mistaken in that normality is not just non-singular in codimension one. Look up Serre's criterion for normality.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot again, your comment is really useful !

Comment: @Mohan : so is there is simple geometric interpretation of normality ?

Comment: What does geometric mean here? Serre's criterion is algebraic (depth).

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks again for your answer. Since I don't know much about commutative algebra, is it true for example that no singularities in codimension $1$ implies that $X$ is normal ?

Comment: I just said that this is not so, like your example, which has only one singular point in codimension 2.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question I was confused. Thanks again for your comments.